# Create a nice alias for a smb share for the command line

Tags: command-line, samba, symbolic-link, sharing

So I would like to be able to use my smb share convienently, however `gvfs` gives it a rather complex name. I have tried a symlink like this to a pre-existing directory `/mnt/qnap`:

```
ln -s /var/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share\:server\=qnap\,share\=transfer/ /mnt/qnap
```

but then I get a link to the last *directory name* (which is still quite cumbersome), not the *contents of the directory*:

```
mike@Abra:~$ ls /mnt/qnap
smb-share:server=qnap,share=transfer
```

Is there a better way to do this? What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried to go inside this directory - `cd /mnt/qnap/smb-share:server=qnap,share=transfer`?

Comment: Does `/mnt/qnap` exist?

Comment: I didn't really try to go inside the directory, but I assume I could. I will when I get back to the computer. And `/mnt/qnap` does exit.

Comment: @pa4080 - yes I could go into that directory.

Comment: Seems to work the way I want it when the directory `/mnt/qnap` is not pre-existing, but now I can't get rid of the previous symlink which has the name I want ... grrrr.

Answer (score 1):

Okay - I learned three things.

1. The answer to my question above was to not pre-create the directory in `/mnt` - @ubashu hinted at this in the comments.
2. But what I really wanted to do was have the smb share mounted at start as per this link: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently
3. And for me that only works if you add a `ver=2.0` to the mount smb initialization string as per this post [CIFS Host is down](https://askubuntu.com/questions/915549/16-04-cifs-host-is-down-but-they-are-not)