# How to mount smb share on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, mount, 18.04

I mounted a shared server on my local network using the GUI connect to server and the address I entered was `smb://myServer/myFolder`. Then i tried to add the shared folder to the `/mnt` directory so I can access to it through my IDE but I failed even though I tried unmount the server and use the CLI with the command

```
gio mount smb://myServer/myFolder**.
```

Anyone had this problem before?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently The above was something I found and though I cannot confirm that it works with 18.04 it definitely works with 20.04LTS. Hopefully, this will be of use to others.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I opened the server i shared and typed **ifconfig** to get the ip adress. Then I typed this command  to list of shares

```
smbclient -L //myServerIpAdress
```

Then to mount it I typed these 2 commands: first to create a folder under the **/mnt** and then to do the mount

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/myFolder

sudo mount -t cifs -o username=serverUserName //myServerIpAdress/sharename /mnt/myFolder/
```

Then enter the server's password when asked and your mount is done under **/mnt/myFolder**

Comment: I kept seeing this error: `mount: /mnt/my-mount-name: cannot mount //<server-ip>/path/to/share read-only.`, and eventually figured out that I had to install `cifs-utils` first (`sudo apt install cifs-utils`). After that the mount command worked.

Comment: I had to add few things: 
`sudo mount -t cifs -o uid=<linuxuser>,username=<serveruser>,dom=<serverdomain> //server/folder /local/folder/`
uid to be able to write to the folders; dom to provide the correct domain name;

Comment: If you get the `cannot mount read-only` error, please run `sudo apt-get install cifs-utils`

Comment: sudo apt install smbclient

Comment: thanks @Wizard79 , after install `cifs-utils` and use @MiroJanosik command, I've successfully mount SMB folder to my ubuntu

Comment: for guest (anonymous) access, this is my line:       sudo mount -t cifs -o guest,username=user,uid=user //server/share local_folder

Comment: If you get error  -2 on ioctl to get interface list                                                                
[   81.093777] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2 you have to install package keyutils

Answer (score 26):

I just followed the [Ubuntu wiki smb guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) and it worked for me with Ubuntu 18.04.1

Specifically:
I first creating the directory for the mount

```
sudo mkdir /media/NAS
```

I added the following line to my fstab

```
//192.168.1.209/public /media/NAS cifs guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

and then ran

```
sudo mount -a
```

From then my NAS drive was mounted. I have rebooted my machine several times and confirmed that it now mounted and start up for me. For what its worth I'm using an Ethernet connection so it could be configured and up and running quicker than a wi-fi connection would be.

Comment: This worked for me I just needed to make sure that `cifs-utils` was installed for. `sudo apt-get install cifs-utils`.

Comment: `mount error(95): Operation not supported`

Comment: Same thing for me @crusy

Comment: `mount error: cifs filesystem not supported by the system` on Windows Subsystem for Linux (not strictly speaking Ubuntu)

Answer (score 8):

Note, that you might better add the SMB protocol version (e.g.vers=1.0) to the mount options. The mount.cifs states to use vers=1.0 as default, but it doesn't and you are trapped with a "host down" error when trying to mount to an older NAS.
The above solution then reads

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=serverUserName,vers=1.0 //myServerIpAdress/sharename /mnt/myFolder/
```

See [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/915549/16-04-cifs-host-is-down-but-they-are-not) for details.

Comment: i get 'read-only' error

Answer (score 5):

If you have installed `gvfs-bin` you can run:

`gvfs-mount smb://username@servername/sharename/`

More about gvfs-mount on [manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/gvfs-mount.1.html)

Also you can read official wiki [Samba/SambaClientGuide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaClientGuide)

Comment: This tool has been deprecated, use 'gio mount' instead.

Comment: it says "volume doesn't implement mount"

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu 18.04, the GNOME Virtual Filesystem mounted from Nautilus can be found in `/run/user/1000/gvfs`. For example, one can `cd` into a Samba share with

```bsh
cd /run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=media,share=sda1
```

Answer (score 2):

I always wanted to use stored passwords from my keyring for accessing SMB shares in scripts (backups) on my laptop. My aim was not to expose the passwords in files and use anacron to run the backups. After some testing I came up with this:

1. Mount your share once via Nautilus and store the password in the keyring
2. try `gio mount smb://<server_name>/<share_name>`, what should work without password in your GNOME session
3. Use the following code in backup scripts:

Example tested on Ubuntu 19.04:

```
# set the dbus address
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/$(id -u)/bus"
# export dbus address to get access to user space keyring
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
# use new gnome user space mount tool (gvfs-mount is deprecated)
gio mount smb://<server_name>/<share_name>
#sync from gvfs created mount point to home dir 
rsync -rav /var/run/user/$(id -u)/gvfs/smb-share\:server\=<server_name>\,share\=<share_name>/<folder>/ ~/<sync_dest>/
```

When running the script via anacron from /etc/cron.daily you need to use the user that has access to the keyring, e.g.:

su -c /home/user/scripts/rsync_sript.sh user

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @Phoenix87 helped me a lot to get access to a samba-drive that is already mounted via Nautilus, but not shown in VSCode. So I put a link under `/home/user/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` and now can open a workspace via smb in VSCode too.

Answer (score 0):

SMBv1 and shares without password protection get the job done quick and easy. But they are definitely a huge security issues (e.g. WannaCry, etc).

Recommend SMBv3 shares with password protection of shares. Using secured credential files in fstab is probably wise too. Linux client side is very similar to above.  See procedures at https://acloudguru.com/blog/engineering/ubuntu-samba-client-setup-and-persistent-shares