# Mounting Windows share with user password

Tags: 18.04, mount

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.  If I open the "Files" GUI, I can browse (via "Other Locations") to `smb://server-name/home`.  The GUI automatically fetches my login credentials and forwards them to the SMB server.

I would like to turn this into a file-system path so that I can use command line tools.  The obvious approach is to use `mount`.  However all the instructions I have seen (for example, the answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050460/how-to-mount-smb-share-on-ubuntu-18-04)) either involve re-entering my password (tedious), or storing the password on disk (insecure).

---

Edit:

I would like to mount an smb share that requires a username+password without having to provide either (but just use my login credentials).  I do not want to store a copy of the password on disk.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, could you please elaborate? Are you asking how to mount smb share without providing password while it requires a password?

Comment: @marosg Is that clearer?

Comment: but, aren't your login credentials stored on disk already?

Comment: Didn't Nautilus ask you once about the credentials and you ticked "Keep forever" or similar? Then @Graham's comment applies.

Comment: If you use a `.smbcredentials` with proper rights (e.g. `600`) you're fine. Because I assume that if you worry about data on your disk you use full-disk encryption anyways.