# NAS Drive connection useing CIFS

Tags: fstab

I have 2 workstations, 1 running Ubuntu Mate 16.04 64bit and 1 running Ubuntu Mate 16.04 32bit. Both machines have cifs-utils and samba installed and the 64bit machine connects to my NAS, no problem but the 32bit returns "mount-error(112) Host is Down yet I can connect to the NAS using "Connect to Server"... What am I missing? Both fstab files refer to a credentials file which are identical on both machines and the line //ipadress/share etc etc are the same on both machines. Please help before I pull all of my hair out. I've done a lot of searching on askubuntu and google to no avail.

Comment: Maybe the network is not yet connected when `fstab` entries are mounted. Can you add the `noauto` option and then mount it manually using `sudo mount /path/to/mountpoint` ?

Comment: It used to work until I re-installed Ubuntu Mate.

Comment: You may find some help here: https://serverfault.com/questions/414074/mount-cifs-host-is-down or here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/915549/16-04-cifs-host-is-down-but-they-are-not

Answer (score 0):

The problem that caused the error message "mount error (112): Host is down" was that I failed to state the Version in the fstab entry, something I didn't have to do in the 64 bit version.
My fstab entry now reads:
//192.168.?.?/sourcelocation home//alan/Documents cifs iocharset=utf8,credentialsfile=/credlocation,uid=1000,gid=1000,vers=1.0  0   2
All is now working fine