# SMB cifs wont automout using vers=3.0 in Ubuntu Server 18.04LTS /etc/fstab while using credentials file

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, automount, cifs

If I login and manually run `mount -a` it mounts without any problems. But auto-mount is not running.

I've tried the following:

```
`//192.168.0.85/someshare/Directory /var/log/remoteMount cifs auto,credentials=/home/admin/.smbcredentials,vers=3.0,iocharset=utf8,noperm 0 0`

//192.168.0.85/someshare/Directory /var/log/remoteMount cifs credentials=/home/admin/.smbcredentials,vers=3.0,iocharset=utf8,noperm,_netdev 0 0

`//192.168.0.85/someshare/Directory /var/log/remoteMount cifs credentials=/home/admin/.smbcredentials,vers=3.0,iocharset=utf8,noperm,_netdev,x-systemd.automount 0 0`

`//192.168.0.85/someshare/Directory /var/log/remoteMount cifs credentials=/home/admin/.smbcredentials,vers=3.0,iocharset=utf8,noperm,x-systemd.automount 0 0`
```

Each time on boot i get the following error in dmesg `CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2`

In all the above attempts, auto-mount does not work (each time tested by rebooting and checking for directory contents). However each time i ran `mount -a` everything works.

How can i get auto-mount working in `/etc/fstab` when using `ver=3.0` and when using `.smbcredentials` instead of storing username and password in `/etc/fstab`?

UPDATE:

Also tried:

`//192.168.0.85/someshare/Directory /var/log/remoteMount cifs credentials=/home/admin/.smbcredentials,vers=3.0,iocharset=utf8,noperm,noauto,x-systemd.automount 0 0`
 which won't automount or mount with `mount -a`

Using `@reboot sleep 10; mount -a` in root `crontab` with the first thing i tried in `/etc/fstab` for now.

Comment: Can we assume that `admin` does not have an encrypted home directory?

Comment: @steeldriver correct

Answer (score 0):

A useful thread [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/915549/16-04-cifs-host-is-down-but-they-are-not)

I have faced this problem before and have used vers=1.0 which works perfectly.

You could also try mount `-a -vvv` to give a verbose version of the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use x-systemd.automount you have to add the noauto option to your list:

```
//192.168.0.85/someshare/Directory /var/log/remoteMount cifs credentials=/home/admin/.smbcredentials,vers=3.0,iocharset=utf8,noperm,noauto,x-systemd.automount 0 0
```

I don't think specifying the smb dialect as 3.0 is the issue since the version of mount.cifs in 18.04 already does that by default if the server allows it.