# I have no writable permission to samba share

Tags: networking, server, samba

I tried to create a file on a samba share with ver 4.10.6 but failed.

I used the folder `/home/ppp/share` for samba, with the following 
`smb.conf`:

```
#
#======================= Global Settings =====================================
[global]

   workgroup = MYGROUP

   server string = Samba Server

   vfs objects = full_audit
   full_audit:prefix = [%U:%g@%I]
   full_audit:success = all
   full_audit:failure = all
   full_audit:facility = local7
   full_audit:priority = info

   server role = standalone server

   log file = /usr/local/samba/var/log.%m

   max log size = 50

   dns proxy = no 

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   path = /usr/spool/samba
   browseable = no
   guest ok = no
   writable = no
   printable = yes

[public]
   path = /home/ppp/share
   available = yes
   valid users = ppp
   read only = no
   browseable = yes
   public = yes
   create mask = 0777
   directory mask = 0777
   force user = ppp
```

I already did `smbpasswd` to add user `ppp` and the share name is `public`

But I only can read and write in existing files, but can't create file.

I tried two ways:

1. Mount it an another Ubuntu server which install samba ver 4.3.11:

   ```
   $ sudo mount -t cifs -o username=ppp,password=admin //192.168.80.108/public /home/otherppp/share
   $ touch /home/otherppp/share/hihi
   $ cannot touch /home/otherppp/test/hihi: Input/output error
   ```
2. Create new file from a Windows 10 share:

   ```
    Can't create file...
   ```

*Can anyone help me?*

=============== udpate ===============

When I update the samba version from 4.3.11 to 4.10.6, it solved.

Comment: And what are the rights on `/home/ppp/share`? `777` too?

Comment: @Fabby the permission is 755

Comment: Set to `777` (world-read-write-execute) and try again.  I can also see some discrepancies between your share `/home/ppp/share` and the mount itself `public /home/otherppp/test` so double-check that too and [edit] your question and feed back please.

Comment: @Fabby set to 777 and also the same result. I try to make both side the same samba version to 4.10.6. It's finally ok.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [16.04 CIFS "Host is down" but they are not](https://askubuntu.com/questions/915549/16-04-cifs-host-is-down-but-they-are-not)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've started to use your question as a pointer to another answer that has the same solution as yours...

Comment: @Fabby I solve it when I update the both side samba to the same version, but maybe somebody wouldn't want to update.